# Refund PayPal PAYID using v2 REST API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have used the Amelia Booking plugin for my one of the site.

I would like to implement the split payment & refund to customer functionality with PayPal payment gateway.

I made one addon for my site which can split the payment using PayPal payout APIs(https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts).

Split is working fine but to make a refund I need customer's PayPal details.

So I did below things:

Amelia is storing the transaction information in the database in below format.

```
{   
    "data": 
    {        
     "PayerId": "4ABCDEFGHIJKL",                 
     "PaymentId": "PAYID-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO2PQRSTUVW", 
     "transactionReference": "PAYID-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO2PQRSTUVW"
    }, 
    "amount": "00.00", 
    "gateway": "payPal", 
    "currency": "USD"
}
```

So from above information I can access "**transactionReference**" to fetch the customer's details using ([https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/{transactionReference}](https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/%7BtransactionReference%7D)) API call to make refund.

But unfortunately this endpoint is deprecated, so is there anyway to fetch the customer's PayPal data using above information from PayPal v2 API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v1 APIs are deprecated for new integrations, but if you are currently using them to process payments -- which if you have a PAYID, you are in fact doing -- then you must use the v1 API for refunds.

Using the v2 API for refunds is only applicable if you are using something like the v2/checkout/orders API to process payments, which that plugin is not doing.